# What does has_external_branch mean when using Visual Studio 2012 CodeCoverage.exe tool?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I'm using Visual Studio 2012's CodeCoverage.exe tool to gather code coverage statistics for a native C++ binary.

I noticed that running `CodeCoverage.exe collect` seemed to ignore many functions.

When running `CodeCoverage.exe analyze /include_skipped_functions` on the .coverage file, many of the missing functions are marked as skipped with a reason of "has_external_branch."

What does this mean?